# 画像のようなエラーがでるのですがどのようにすればよろしいでしょうか

Tags: python

こちらのサイト通りにすすめており、main.py でエラーが出ました。

https://github.com/Lincoln-LM/pla-reverse-gui/wiki/Usage-Guide

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: エラーメッセージに`import`出来なかったと表示されている`QWebEngineScrip`は、実際にはこちらの[QWebEngineScript](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtWebEngineCore/QWebEngineScript.html)でしょうから、最後の`t`が抜けています。何かインストールが不完全だった、あるいはインストール後に壊れた/壊された、といったことが発生したのではないでしょうか？ いったんPython関連を完全にアンインストールしてから再インストールしてみてはどうでしょう？ 完全なアンインストールはこんな記事を参考に。[＼完全解決‼／Pythonを完全にアンインストールする方法を解説‼](https://information-station.work/5395/), [Pythonを完全にアンインストールする方法（Windows）](https://gammasoft.jp/support/uninstall-python-completely-on-windows/)

Comment: アンインストールして再度同じようにインストールしたのですが同じエラーが出ます

Comment: こちらのWindows11 Python 3.10.11 で問題発生個所の`from pyqtlet2 import L, MapWidget`である`pyqtlet2`および`PyQt6`関連の最低限のモジュールをインストールした環境で該当行を試したところでは、問題は発生しませんでした。謎ですね。可能性は低いですが、Pythonをインストールした際に[4.1.2. MAX_PATH の制限を除去する](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/using/windows.html#removing-the-max-path-limitation)を行っていないとか？ あるいは pip, setuptools, wheel の各モジュールが最新版では無いとか？ 取り敢えずそれ以外は思いつきません。

Comment: windows10です。

Comment: 足りないというｔを書き足すのはどうすればいいですか

Comment: おそらく [QtPy - PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/QtPy/), [PySide6 - PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/PySide6/), [PyQt6-WebEngine - PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt6-WebEngine/) といったモジュール/パッケージの中のコンパイルされた後の中身の話なので、その中の特定の何かだけ変更/対策することは出来ないでしょう。そうした内部に関わっていそうな話は知識・経験が無いので残念ながら私から何か言えることはありません。

Answer (score 1):

こちらのサイトにのっている最新のツールがscriptのｔが抜けていることが原因で
C:\pla-reverse-gui\Lib\site-packages\qtpy\QtWebEngineWidgets.py
の64行目付近に"Scrip"となっている箇所があるので"Script"に直したら動くようになりました