# 画像のようなエラーがでるのですがどうすればいいでしょうか

Tags: python

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

https://github.com/Lincoln-LM/pla-reverse-gui/wiki/Usage-Guide#requirements

こちらのサイトにそってやってます。どうすればいいでしょうか

Comment: 質問はあとからでも編集できるので、もし追加情報があるなら [元の投稿](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/96145) を編集してください。似たような質問をいくつも投稿しても情報が分散されて回答が付きづらくなります。

Comment: 前回の質問とは別のモジュール名・別のエラーメッセージになったようなので別件とするのも良いですが、その場合前回の質問は解決したということでしょうか？ 解決したなら情報共有のために、その判明した原因や行った対処の詳細を自己回答としてみてください。[自分の質問に回答できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) あるいは cubick さんコメントのように、最初の問題に対処したが(細部は違うとはいえ)類似のエラーが発生した新しい状況ということで、完全解決に至っていないので前回の質問記事に新しい内容を追記するという方法もあります。ただ、いずれにしろスクリーンショットではなくテキストで記事を書くようにしてください。[スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3765) コマンドプロンプトウインドウ上で Ctrl-A, Ctrl-C して、何かのテキストエディタで Ctrl-V すればテキストで取得出来るはずです。事前にコマンドプロンプトウインドウのプロパティをそれらが使えるように変更しておく必要があるかもしれませんが。

Comment: エラーメッセージの内容から推測するとPythonのモジュール以外にもOpenCLのランタイム等をインストールする必要があるのでは？ [超簡単‼Open CL Application Intelのインストール方法(windows10)](https://information-station.work/458/), [Python OpenCL入門](https://mkguytone.github.io/pyopencl/), [PyOpenCL のインストール](https://www.tomoyan.net/python/pyopencl) `OpenCL を利用するには OS プラットフォームに関係なく、OpenCL 開発環境構築 が必要である。`

Comment: ありがとうございます。いわれてる通りインストールしたら起動しました。

Comment: cubickさん、kunifさん申し訳ございません。エラーメッセージをコピペしてそのまま検索してpythonについて質問できるサイトを見つけて使い方もわからないままサイトの利用をしておりました。質問の終わらせ方もわかっていなかったので教えてくださり感謝しております。

Comment: ツールは問題なく起動できたのですが、そのあとスクリプト通りにすすめていると新たにコマンドプロンプトで以下のようなエラーメッセージがでました。
C:\Users\81802\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyopencl\__init__.py:270: CompilerWarning: Non-empty compiler output encountered. Set the environment variable PYOPENCL_COMPILER_OUTPUT=1 to see more.
  warn("Non-empty compiler output encountered. Set the "

このエラーはどのような解決方法がありますでしょうか。

Comment: 表示されているのは`CompilerWarning`なので`警告`ではあっても`エラー`では無いですね。検索するとこんな記事があって昔から発生しているようです。[CompilerWarning with OpenCL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20722242/9014308), [\[PyOpenCL\] Non-empty compiler output warning from Intel OpenCL](https://pyopencl.tiker.narkive.com/Fqz3pIJ1/non-empty-compiler-output-warning-from-intel-opencl) 気になるならメッセージのとおり環境変数に`PYOPENCL_COMPILER_OUTPUT`を追加定義して値を`1`に設定してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: システム環境変数でpathの項目で新規で設定したらよろしいでしょうか

Comment: 違いは無いはずですのでどちらでも試してみては？ 状況が変わらないとか、更なるあるいは別の問題が出るなら戻せば良いわけですし。

Comment: 次に進むことができたのですが、またエラーが出ました。Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pla-reverse-gui\pla_reverse_gui\kernel_interface.py", line 102, in run
    expected_seeds = pla_reverse.odds.calc_expected_seeds(
  File "C:\pla-reverse-gui\pla_reverse_gui\pla_reverse_main\pla_reverse\odds.py", line 38, in calc_expected_seeds
    * calc_size_list_odds(sizes)
  File "C:\pla-reverse-gui\pla_reverse_gui\pla_reverse_main\pla_reverse\odds.py", line 20, in calc_size_list_odds
    return 1 / total_odds
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
これはどのようなエラーですか。

Comment: エラーに書かれているのは`ZeroDivisionError`で、[Lincoln-LM/pla-reverse/pla_reverse/odds.py#L20](https://github.com/Lincoln-LM/pla-reverse/blob/99d716828ee1de5292bb57e8050875383a6725b4/pla_reverse/odds.py#L20)の`return 1 / total_odds`の`total_odds`が`0`だったということでしょう。現在でも活発に活動されているリポジトリらしいので、何か途中経過で一時的な物かもしれません。ただし個人でやってそうなのでリポジトリのオーナーしか答えられる人は居ないのでは？ [Lincoln-LM/pla-reverse-gui/issues](https://github.com/Lincoln-LM/pla-reverse-gui/issues)に新しい`Issue`を出して聞いてみてはどうでしょう？

Answer (score 1):

OpenCLのruntimeをインストールすることで解決いたしました。